# BroadcastReceiver ClassNotFoundException Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to run the below code to start `BroadCastReceiver`. there is a `custom notification` and a `buttonview` to it, when i click the button the notification will close, but it is giving the below exception.

and i have created the `notification channel` for `API 26` and above in `OnCreate` method too

```
public void OpenActivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DrawRect));
         intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

         RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.NotificationLayout);

         int notificationId = (int)SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis();
         Intent buttonIntent = new Intent("button_clicked");
         buttonIntent.PutExtra("id", notificationId);

         PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = 
         PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, notificationId, buttonIntent, 0);

         remoteView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.cloceNotification, 
         buttonPendingIntent);

         NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new 
         NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Diet")
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
                        .SetContentTitle("Diet")
                        .SetContentText("My App")
                    .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh).SetContentIntent(pendingIntent).SetOngoing(true).SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()).SetCustomContentView(remoteView);


         NotificationManagerCompat notificationCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
         notify.Build().Flags |= NotificationFlags.OnlyAlertOnce;
         notificationCompat.Notify(notificationId, notify.Build());
         FinishAndRemoveTask();
     }
```

**BroadCastReceiver Class:**

```
public class Button_listener : BroadcastReceiver
    {
         public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
         {
              NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);
              notificationManager.Cancel(intent.GetIntExtra("id",1));
              Toast.MakeText(context, "From Broadcaster", ToastLength.Long).Show();
          }
    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="DietCam.DietCam" android:installLocation="auto">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  android:debuggable="true">
         <activity android:label="DrawRect" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" android:name="md580a1eddd40074c89f21a5ec99d8b044c.DrawRect"  android:screenOrientation="sensor"/>
          <activity android:label="SplashScreen" android:name="md580a1eddd40074c89f21a5ec99d8b044c.SplashScreen">

          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>   

        <receiver android:name=".Main.Button_listener">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="button_clicked"/>
                </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

**Exception:**

```
Unhandled Exception:

    Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver DietCam.DietCam.Main.Button_listener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "DietCam.DietCam.Main.Button_listener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/DietCam.DietCam-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/DietCam.DietCam-1/lib/x86, /data/app/DietCam.DietCam-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Comment: Do you have the `BroadcastReceiver` attribute something like `[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]` above your class definition

Comment: no i don't have it.

Comment: add it then and see what happens

Comment: added it,same exception again

Comment: why exactly are you using this broadcast receiver?

Comment: to just close the notification itself and the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189703/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-vinnusaurus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `<receiver>` tag from `AndroidManifest.xml` file and added the `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentFilter` `attributes` to the `BroadcastReceiver class`

**Removed the below tag from Manifest file**

```
<receiver android:name=".Main.Button_listener">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="button_clicked"/>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Added Attributes to BroadcastReceiver class:**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "button_clicked" } )]
public class Button_listener : BroadcastReceiver
{
     public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
          NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

          notificationManager.Cancel(intent.GetIntExtra("id",1));
          Toast.MakeText(context, "From Broadcaster", ToastLength.Long).Show();
     }
}
```